# Virtual consoles on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, tty, virtual-console

In [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) link is mentioned that Linux GUI is installed on *tty7*, but when I change my consoles using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> and check it by the command `tty`, I see that I have a GUI on my *tty1* and *tty2*.
I'd like to know:

- Why is in most sources mentioned that the GUI is on *tty7*?
- I have a GUI on my *tty1* and *tty2* on Ubuntu 20.04, *tty3-6* are consoles without GUI and *tty7* prints information about  `/dev/sda2`, is tty7 another console? If yes how does it differ from other consoles? If no, what is it?

Comment: Your own Wikipedia link says *"usually"*...

Comment: Some docs are dated. Much has changed from X11 to Wayland, Gnome, KDE, etc. Does tty7 always show this output, even after a clean boot?